# what causing an error about 'lc-messages-dir' how can i fix it

Tags: mysql5

```
    ./mysqld --initialize --user=mysql --basedir=/opt/mysql/mysql --datadir=/opt/mysql/mysql/data
    [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
    [Warning] 'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict mode in a future release.
    [Warning] 'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER' sql mode was not set.
    [ERROR] Can't find error-message file '/opt/mysql/mysql/data/errmsg.sys'. Check error-message file location and 'lc-messages-dir' configuration directive.
    [Warning] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=45790
    [Warning] InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables.
    [Warning] No existing UUID has been found, so we assume that this is the first time that this server has been started. Generating a new UUID: 73963455-d30a-11e6-bf4f-3aa0c659e827.
    [Warning] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.
    [Note] A temporary password is generated for root@localhost: t&VhwEgod4rm

there is an error about  'lc-messages-dir'  i want to know what's that and how i can fix it?
```

> im running: centos6.4  mysql-5.7.17-linux-glibc2.5-x86_64

Answer (score 0):

mysqld depends on corresponding values in errmsg.sys. If you see error like that - mysqld cannot find errmsg.sys at location. Needs proper installation and/or make sure that lc_messages_dir is configured properly in my.cnf